# how to use reduce function to add every tuple2's value from every inner List

Tags: scala

a List for example:

```
List(List((0,1), (1,2), (0,0), (1,1)),List((0,1), (1,2), (2,2), (3,3)))
```

expected:

```
List((0,2), (2,4), (2,2), (4,4))
```

how to use reduce function to add every tuple2's value from each inner List

```
List(List((0,1), (1,2), (0,0), (1,1)),List((0,1), (1,2), (2,2), (3,3))).reduce((a,b)=>a.zip(b))
```

i don't know how to realize it,so ask for help.  thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. After the lists have been zipped, `map` over it so that the resulting list of type `List[((Int,Int),(Int,Int))]` can be combined to the desired type `List[(Int,Int)]`.

```
lst.reduce { (x, y) =>
  x zip y map {case ((a,b),(c,d)) => (a+c,b+d)}
}
```

You might also consider using `zipAll()` just in case there are internal lists of different lengths.

```
lst.reduce { (x, y) =>
  x.zipAll(y,(0,0),(0,0)).map{case ((a,b),(c,d)) => (a+c,b+d)}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@jwvh's answer should suffice your problem. But if you would like yet another way to try, then you can try as following too.

```
val list = List(List((0,1), (1,2), (0,0), (1,1)),List((0,1), (1,2), (2,2), (3,3)))
list.reduce((a,b) => a.zip(b).map(tuple => (tuple._1._1 + tuple._2._1, tuple._1._2 + tuple._2._2)))
```